# Are movie Character guides/companion books on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This question [Why was the Obscurus omitted?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/117/why-was-the-obscurus-omitted#118)
is asking about missing details from a movie character guide. This is not a novelization, it is for lack of a better word, an encyclopedia, containing information pertaining to the movie, with pictures. The companion guides/handbooks are in the same boat, they offer tidbits of additional information, but not an actual story.

Comment: vtc'd because I think it's better to set a broader precedent

Comment: mine is literally as broad as the other, they are identical.

Comment: to be horribly pedantic, yours is specifically about character guides/companions, mine's about movie companion books in general.  I do concede that they're very close

Comment: So which part of character guides and/or companion books my question askes about is more exclusive then yours

Comment: @Himarm I guess the way I've been reading your title and your post is that they're specifically about CHARACTERS, rather than the movie as a whole.